# I need to change background of the last nested element using css

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background color of last nested element. I am using following css but it is not working

```
.cd-timeline > .year-wrapper > .cd-timeline-block:last-of-type{ 
    background-color:red;
}
```

i also tried

```
#cd-timeline .year-wrapper  .cd-timeline-block:last-of-type{ 
    background-color:red;
}
```

What am i doing wrong can we use `last-of-type` element with class

Fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/shfh0x63/2/

```
<div class="timeline-wrapper">
    <div class="cd-container" id="cd-timeline">
        <div class="year-wrapper">
            <div class="cd-timeline-block">1</div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-block">2</div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-block">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="year-wrapper">
            <div class="cd-timeline-block">4</div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-block">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="year-wrapper">
            <div class="cd-timeline-block">6</div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-block">7</div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-block">8</div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-block">change background color of this only</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have use undefined selector (`.cd-timeline` instead of `#cd-timeline` - in HTML you have `ID`, not `class`). Then you need to add `last-of-type` to `.year-wrapper` too

```
#cd-timeline > .year-wrapper:last-of-type > .cd-timeline-block:last-of-type{ background-color:red;}
^                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/shfh0x63/3/

Comment: I was so close. Thanks

Comment: Considering all the elements are `divs`, there's no real need to use `last-of-type` anyway, just use `:last-child`

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest way of doing it using :last-child

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/50e6sput/))

```
.year-wrapper:last-child .cd-timeline-block:last-child {
    background-color: red;
}
```